# The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata

Tags: java, android, android-studio

The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1.
AAR metadata file: C:\Users\adpardes.gradle\caches\transforms-3\f0dcb4f67d8fb9042adaf3c4bf6ff21e\transformed\appcompat-1.4.1\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

How to solve this error. Before that it was showing like the 34 version was currupted so I changed it to 30

Comment: minSdk version can not be greater than compileSdk. While your compileSdk was 30, your minSdk was 31. that's why you encountered this error. Set the compileSdk and targetSdk to 33 and minSdk to 24 (or any value smaller than 33). Hopefully, it will fix this error.

Comment: In build.gradle (app) changing  Compile SDK version to 31 worked for me

Comment: If you plan to publish the app on the play store, it's best to use the latest SDK version in compile and target SDK.